Ore- condition of morphisms whose cones lie in a triangulated subcategory
I'm having trouble proving a statement about multiplicative systems related to triangulated subcategories.

Let $\mathcal{T}$ be a triangulated category and $\mathcal{D} \subset \mathcal{T}$ a triangulted subcategory.

Let $\Sigma_\mathcal{D}$ be the class of morphisms $f$ in $\mathcal{T}$ such that $\text{cone}\,f \in \mathcal{D}$.

I'm trying to prove that $\Sigma_\mathcal{D}$ satifies the Ore-condition that is


(Ore condition) Let $t: Z\longrightarrow Y$ be in $\Sigma_\mathcal{D}$. Then for each                                $g: M \longrightarrow Y$ in $\mathcal{T}$ there is an $s\in \Sigma_\mathcal{D}$ and an $h \in \mathcal{T}$ making the diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
W @>{h}>> Z\\
@V{s}VV @V{t}VV\\
M @>{g}>> Y
\end{CD}$$
commute. Moreover, the symmetric statement, where $s$ is given and $t$ exists, holds too.
I can find the maps $h$ and $s$ by taking $W = \text{cone}\,(t -g)$ and the corresponding morphisms. But I can't show that $s$ is in $\Sigma_{\mathcal{D}}$. I've looked it up, and found Neemans book on triangulated categories, more precisely, Lemma 1.4.4, but I don't understand how he gets the triangle $Z \longrightarrow Z' \longrightarrow Y'' \longrightarrow Z[1]$.
This question is now on MO https://mathoverflow.net/questions/476039/ore-condition-of-morphisms-whose-cone-lies-in-a-triangulated-subcategory
